# How could I (temporarily) un-typedef something?

Tags: c++

I'm using a 3rd party library that `typedef`s `byte` to `char`.

(This is evil as `char` could be `signed` or `unsigned` depending on the compiler's choice).

Unfortunately that `typedef` has spilled over into the codebase that I maintain and I'm keen to remove them: using `uint8_t` directly instead.

Is there a way I can somehow *undo* this `typedef` once I get to my code (i.e. direcly after `#include <3rdpartylib>`)?

I will be in a position to remove the "solution" from my codebase once I've removed all the `byte`s.

Comment: xyz will do, it means the 3rd party library really calls their typedef xyz and not byte anymore...

Comment: "Spilled over"? You mean the coders (perhaps yourself)  use `byte` although they shouldn't? Wouldn't that be easy to fix?

Comment: Yup but even easier if I can get the *compiler* to help me point out where the `byte`s are. @Deduplicator's solution is working well!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way is bracketing the includes of the 3rd-party-library thus:

```
#define byte somethingnotnamedbyte
#include <3rdpartylib>
#undef byte
```

That avoids the need to edit `<3rdpartylib>`, and avoids polluting your code with macros or that bad typedef.

**Precondition:** The preprocessing-token `byte` is only used as that typedef-name in `<3rdpartylib>`, never for anything else.

Comment: This is incredibly hackish, but yeah, if the library doesn't properly use namespaces to prevent name clashes, it's the only thing you can do.

Comment: @MarcusJ No. But you can use a `#define` to substitute something else for the identifier otherwise poisoned by the typedef in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to do this. Undef only works on macros.