# openvc and tiff, error typedef redefinition with different types int64_t

Tags: c++, opencv, tiff, clang++, vcpkg

I have a Qt C++ project which depends on opencv and tiff (installed with vcpkg) among other things.

It's originally developed on Windows (microsoft compiler) and now I'm trying to build it on macOS (clang). I'm in the mid of figuring out how to provide all dependencies.

I'm on the same vcpkg commit id `acb6b10e7fdf5e8519c18398d0b069e1d58ca025` on macOS, as it is on Windows (x64-windows). By doing so I think I'm  using same lib versions.

However on macOS I see

```
vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h:61:20: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('int64_t' (aka 'long long') vs 'long')
   typedef int64_t int64;
                   ^
vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include/tiff.h:75:23: note: previous definition is here
typedef TIFF_INT64_T  int64;
                      ^
```

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undef a typedef in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435565/undef-a-typedef-in-c)

Comment: Update your vcpkg to the newest version and rebuild everything. If this doesn't fix it, open up an issue on vcpkg and cc @cenit